# Fetch php curl GET command returns 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 4814'

Tags: php, curl, fetch

Using a Fetch() method to call a curl GET function within a php file. PHP webserver confirmed as working (phpinfo) and JSON data is being returned when inspecting the Network > pCurl.php > Preview (in Chrome). However I still get the syntax error.

fetch code:

```
var curl = "js/pCurl.php"

fetch(curl)
  .then(
    function(response) {
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

pCurl.php:

```
<?php
function httpGet($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();

  // set URL and other appropriate options
  $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                     "api-auth:1111111-1111-11111-111111",
                   )
                  );

  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

  $output=curl_exec($ch);

  //Check for errors.
  if(curl_errno($ch)){
      //If an error occured, throw an Exception.
      throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
      curl_close($ch);
  }

  curl_close($ch);
  return $output;
}

echo httpGet("https://public-api.adsbexchange.com/VirtualRadar/AircraftList.json?lat=-35.307500&lng=149.124417&fDstL=0&fDstU=100");
?>
```

Upon inspection of the returned JSON you can see plain as day that a '1' is sitting outside the containing { }. I've no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                     "api-auth:1111111-1111-11111-111111",
                   ),
                   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
                  );
```

So turns out I needed to include a returntransfer in the curl options, because the echo calling httpGet() was returning true - or '1'.

Thanks to James at ADSBx for pointing this out!